# In the top left corner there is a Tibetan Buddhist praying. Can you translate this prayer?

Tags: translation, tibetan

[image: Faith Card]

So, apparently, this won't let me post unless I have thirty characters, so I'm going to ask the same question in the comments. In the above image, a Tibetan Buddhist is praying (or speaking, what have you) in the top left corner. Can you translate this prayer?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it doesn't look like Tibetan, but rather like Sanskrit or Pali. It's a little hard to make out, but it could be part of the [Prajna-Paramita (Heart) Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_Sutra).

Having said that, Buddhism (and especially Mahayana Buddhism from which this Sutra originates) has little to do with faith. As opposed to the Abrahamic religions depicted here, Mahayana Buddhism is experiential, not axiomatic. The Buddha famously said in the [Kalama Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalama_Sutta):

> Do not go upon what has been acquired by repeated hearing,
>   nor upon tradition,
>   nor upon rumor,
>   nor upon what is in a scripture,
>   nor upon surmise,
>   nor upon an axiom,
>   nor upon specious reasoning,
>   nor upon a bias towards a notion that has been pondered over,
>   nor upon another's seeming ability,
>   nor upon the consideration, The monk is our teacher.